# Admob banner sometimes it's being showed very small

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I am using SMART_BANNER size and i am adding it to bottom of the screen. Some banners are being showed correctly but random ones are being showed with very small size, low height and low width. All of them in the same device (nexus 5)

I develop a small test app to avoid other errors, and this is the code:

I set the size using this:

```
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
```

I add the adView using this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adsParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
adsParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
mainLayout.addView(adView, adsParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

its depends on advertiser what ads they give to google and what size etc
if you want to clear this topic then just promote app and see you can understand .
hope you satisfied with my answer